# Vue.js routing cannot do

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

My vue.js app routing is not working, please help, there is not a lot of code , simply copy paste this code in your index.html, you'll see the weird errors .  its like we cant use scripts when using the vue router.:

```
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Starter Vue.js Bt4</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver"></script>

    <!-- Required scripts -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

</head>
        <body>
            <div class="wrapper" id="app">
            <router-link to="/users">Users</router-link>
            <router-link to="/home">Go to HOME</router-link>
            <router-view></router-view>


            <script type="text/x-template" id="users">
                <p>
                    <ul id="demo">
                      <li v-repeat="items" >
                        {parentMsg}} {{childMsg}}
                          </li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </script>
            
            <script type="text/x-template" id="home">
                <button v-on:click="count++">Vous mavez cliqué {{ count }} fois.</button>
            </script>
        
            
            
            </div>
        </body>


        <script>
        
        
        var Home = { 

            data: function () {
                return {count: 0}
          },template: "#home"
          
        }
        
        const Users= { 

         template: "#users",
          data: {
            items: [
              { childMsg: 'Foo' },
              { childMsg: 'Bar' }
            ]
          }


        }

        const routes = [
          { path: '/home', component:Home},
          { path: '/users', component: Users}
        ]


        const router = new VueRouter({
          routes // short for `routes: routes`
        })


        const app = new Vue({
          router
        }).$mount('#app')

        </script>
```

this is the error it doesnt work, please help : Error nothing works, displaying users is impossible :

```
[Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions. vue.js:634:17
[Vue warn]: Property or method "count" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:634:17
[Vue warn]: Property or method "childMsg" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:634:17
[Vue warn]: Property or method "items" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <Root> vue.js:634:17
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: repeat

(found in <Anonymous>)
```

AngularJs was working all of the time, why this is not working ?
Thanks for helping me, nothing works, files .vue not working either, no explanation, im going back to angularJs thank you

**EDIT :**
template literal not working with routing neither :

const Users= {

```
     template: `
      <p>
            <ul id="demo">
              <li v-repeat="items" >
                {parentMsg}} {{childMsg}}
                  </li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    `,
      data() {
        return {items: [
          { childMsg: 'Foo' },
          { childMsg: 'Bar' }
        ]}
      }
    }
```

**the error :**
**[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: repeat**

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "childMsg" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Anonymous>)
```

**EDIT 2:** It is working with the following template litteral, but i dont want this kind of templating at all , it is not easy to write inside of the javascript, I need to use the  balise or .vue files, and nothing works .:

```
const Users= { 

     template: `
      <p>
            <ul id="demo">
              <li v-for="item in items" >
                {{item.childMsg}} 
            </li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    `,
      data() {
        return {items: [
          { childMsg: 'Foo' },
          { childMsg: 'Bar' }
        ]}
      }
    }
```

Edit, after reading this : https://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url/

I will try to write templates inside of the JS code

EDIT : Resolved there :[Unable to add any module without WebPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506451/unable-to-add-any-module-without-webpack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update couple of things

```
const Users= { 

         template: "#users",
          data() {
           return {
            items: [
              { childMsg: 'Foo' },
              { childMsg: 'Bar' }
            ]
          };
         }
        }
```

You haven't added Home component but still you are using, just remove Home from routes

```
const routes = [
          { path: '/users', component: Users}
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks you , but it still doesnt work : [Vue warn]: Property or method "childMsg" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Comment: it seems that scripts doesnt work with vue.js routing , or that the stuff is bugged

Comment: Yes you need to define a components in a string or try oany one of the approaches https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/03/24/vue-js-component-templates/

Comment: v-repeat was deprecated in 1.0: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1200 <li v-for="item in items">

Comment: Resolved there :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506451/unable-to-add-any-module-without-webpack